# How to sort keys in arrays according to frequency

Tags: javascript, jquery

My submit button is finally working. However, it is not counting all of the votes in the results. How do I get my submit button to sort all of the votes?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="movies.css">
      <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <title> 
    Movie List 
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>My Favorite Movies</h1>
            <div id = "first">
                <input type="text" id="movie" placeholder="Movie">
                <button id="enter">Enter</button>
            </div>
      <div id="left">
        <div id="list"><u>Chosen Films:</u></div>
        <!-- <div>Chosen Films: <span id="list"></span></div> -->
        <!-- <div id="films"></div> -->
        <div id="best"><u>You're Best Films:</u></div>
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

        <div id= "results"><u>Results</u></div>       

    <script type="text/javascript" src="movies.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var films = [];
    // with working vote button
    $("#enter").click(function () {
        var movie = $("#movie").val();
        var $btn = $('<button />', {
            id: "vote",
            type: "button",
            text: "Vote",
            value: movie,
            click: function(){
                var vote = this.value;
                $("#best").append('<p>'+vote+'</p>');
                films.push(vote); 
            }
        });

        var $p = $('<p />');
        $p.append($btn, " ", movie);
        $p.appendTo("#list");
    });
});
```

So here is where the trouble is:

This code should allow the submit button to take the listed films under "your best films" and arrange them in a third list under "results" in order of their votes.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var ballot = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < films.length; i++) {
        var key = films[i];
        ballot[key] = (ballot[key] || 0) + 1;
    }
    var elect = [];
    for (key in ballot) elect.push({key: key, freq: ballot[key]});
    elect.sort(function(a,b){return b.freq - a.freq});
    console.log(elect);
    for (var i = 0; i < elect.length; i++){
        console.log(elect[i].key);
        $("#results").append('<p>' + elect[i].key + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it show any error because I think you have one. I see that you wrote `for ( var i = 1; i < films.length; i++)` but you didn't do something like this `var films = document.querySelector(".flims");  `.

Comment: No errors. just not counting most of the votes, not all of them. Where would that var films line go?

Comment: Well I gues that's because you did `films.length` when you don't have anything called films.

Comment: The films array is right above the $("#enter").click(function () {

Comment: If that is so than you should put the last part where the error is inside that because this way it looks like it's seperated.

Comment: No errors, they array is global, so that part should work.

Comment: You used `i` twice `for (var i; i < films.length; i++)` and `for (var i = 0; i < elect.length; i++;)` change the second `i` into `j` or `k`.

Comment: Tried it. No such luck, showing j/k undefined.

Comment: Did you do it like this `for (var j = 0; j < elect.length; j++;)                                                                 {console.log(elect[j].key);                                          $("#results").append('<p>' + elect[j].key + '</p>');}`

Comment: I got it! my first for loop should have started at 0, not 1. YES!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var ballot = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
         var key = films[i];
        ballot[key] = (ballot[key] || 0) + 1;
        }
    var elect = [];
        for (key in ballot) elect.push({key: key, freq: ballot[key]});
    elect.sort(function(a,b){return b.freq - a.freq});
    console.log(elect);
    for (var j = 0; j < elect.length; j++){
        console.log(elect[j].key);
        $("#results").append('<p>' + elect[j].key + '</p>');
    }
```